# How to prevent Ubuntu from upgrading during boot?

Tags: upgrade

Since the last OS upgrade (20.10), Ubuntu has begun to automatically perform package upgrades on boot.

I hate this. When I boot up my computer, I usually need to use the system right away. I do not want automatic updates and would like to update my software manually.

How can I disable the auto-update feature ?

Comment: Hmmm. What output leads you to believe that the system is automatically performing package upgrades at boot?

Comment: Well. Upon boot, it displays a message saying that upgrade is ongoing, with a progress bar, and that I should not power off the computer. Then it will restart and boot properly.

Comment: A (readable) picture of that screen would be very helpful. You seem to be describing Windows-like update behavior, and Ubuntu is specifically designed to work NOT that way. Also, neither my 20.10 test system nor my 20.10 daily driver are doing that. So I'm confused by your description of the problem -- seems like we lack data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally spotted the place were I can choose the behaviour I want:

if you have upgrades waiting to be installed and you shutdown or restart the computer, then you now have a checkbox saying

> Install pending software upgrades

in the shutdown / restart popup.

It is checked by default, and I didn't pay attention before, as shuting down the computer is not very involving, and the message is not so proeminent.

If you leave it cheked, upgrades will happen on next reboot without further asking you.

So, I have to be cautious, and not leave it checked when shuting down the computer. But at least, I have the choice.

(nb: can't put any screenshot, as it happens just before shuting down and during the boot process)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about `unattended-upgrades`.  [Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) makes sure that your system is up-to-date with security patches and other essential updates like critical bugfixes.  It does not automatically update all of your software.

You can remove this package with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove unattended-upgrades
```

You will still need to update your system regularly, but you will need to do so manually.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` as follows:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Disable `apt-daily.service`, `apt-daily.timer`,`apt-daily-upgrade.service` and `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`:

```
sudo systemctl disable --now  apt-daily{,-upgrade}.service
sudo systemctl disable --now  apt-daily{,-upgrade}.timer
```